# Editing in chat: White text on light blue background

Tags: bug, chat, user-interface

I've been having this problem for a while now – whenever I edit my chat messages, the text is white and displayed on a light blue background, making it impossible to see.

[image: Image 1]

I have to highlight my words to read it, which is rather inconvenient:

[image: Image 2]

I'm using **Chrome Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)**, running on macOS v10.14 (Mojave).

Comment: All chat rooms?  What browser?  (Doesn't happen to me, so trying to narrow it down.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Ah, it's cause of the Grammarly extension so ... indeed a duplicate